# Making Series Solutions Look Nicer

Tags: series-expansion

My students and I are using AsympototicDSolveValue[] to find power series solutions to linear differential equations at 0.   For example, the following code gives me a solution up to degree 7.

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a function that, when applied, forces the output to look like this...

[image] .

The traditional form output makes it look nicer than without, but it reverses the order and doesn't factor out the a0 and a1 terms.  Any ideas?

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] - x y'[x] - y[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == a, 
  y'[0] == b}, y[x], {x, 0, 7}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `Collect` ?

```
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] - x y'[x] - y[x] == Sin[x], 
   y[0] == a[0], y'[0] == a[1]}, y[x], {x, 0, 7}]
Collect[sol, {a[0], a[1]}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> but it reverses the order

To change the order do

```
TraditionalForm[PolynomialForm[sol, TraditionalOrder -> False]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use Matex

```
<< MaTeX`
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] - x y'[x] - y[x] == Sin[x], 
    y[0] == a[0], y'[0] == a[1]}, y[x], {x, 0, 7}];
sol = Collect[sol, {a[0], a[1]}]
MaTeX[ToString[TeXForm[TraditionalForm[PolynomialForm[sol, 
         TraditionalOrder -> False]]]], Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow!  Mathematica is amazing.  Did not know about this function.  TY

Comment: I don't see PolynomialForm[] in the Documentation Center anywhere, but it does appear to allow us to reverse the order.  I'm using MM13.2

Comment: @Bflat it is in the help   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3yX1.png)  but I learned about from this forum. I do not know why it is not in the official documentation center.  May be WRI overlooked it?